# retrieve EditText multiline text as it is android?

Tags: android

I want to get text from Edit text as it is and display in TextView.But whenver i get text using getText() it gives me text in one line. How to entered text in multiline EditText as it is. Please give me guidance?

Comment: You can also achieve this functionality using https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753731/6676310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rajendar,

I don't understand why you're having this issue. When you obtain a piece of text out of an EditText it should keep "formatting" such as line breaks.

For instance, try this code (I tested it myself)!

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/m_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java

```
public class MainTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }


    //button listener
    private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick (View view) {

      EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
      String str = et.getText().toString();

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

      tv.setText(str);
     }
    }; 
}
```

Both Toast and TextView keep line breaks. You can try it yourself.

Maybe if you post your code (the relevant bits, at least) we can help you.

Comment: I need a help here... I want to send the same to server with multi-line, as it displays... I am getting the string with line break, but when i send to server or store in db, it is in single line.. Any clue that how can we solve this?